# Соседи на сервере

Tags: ip, хостинг

Сколько сайтов хостинг имеет право размещать на одном ip? Какое количество допустимо для нормальной работы моего проекта?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще говоря, это зависит от типа и условий хостинга. Для выделенных серверов обычно предоставляется один адрес + какое-то дополнительное количество за отдельную плату. Для виртуальных серверов на разделяемом хостинге, может быть произвольное количество сайтов на одном адресе. Обычно в таком случае сайт - это папка для вебсервера и подключение к базе данных. Все сайты хостера сидят на одно адресе, а вебсервер разруливает их по доменным именам.